# Matching the contents of a binary file from tags (Java)

Tags: java, regex

Have an envelope that I'm passing through a socket. Like

```
<task>
<doc>
This is the contents of a file
</doc>
</task>
```

Works great with text docs using a pattern like "`<doc>(.*?)</doc>`", Pattern.DOTALL
but put the contents of a word doc in there and can't get it out.
Any Ideas?
Jim

Comment: You're putting a Word document _inside_ an XML document?

Comment: Is that really a valid usage of XML? Wouldn't you have to encode your binary data? And then would it not work with a regex? Just curious.

Comment: no it is not xml merely a tagged envelope just to identify info in the tags

Comment: Then why don't you put all the info at the start, and the data follows. What's the point of having closing tags if it's not XML?

Comment: Makes matching the between tags content easier, see Pattern above

Comment: except it won't work if your file contains `</doc></task>`

Comment: Easier than just reading header first and then body? Good thing they didn't design the HTTP protocol like that. :)

Comment: well the idea is that I can have multiple tasks inside of a set of <batch></batch> tags, also add tagged info to a task like <doc_name></doc_name>, etc

Comment: If it should be XML after all then at least base64-encode the binary data.

Comment: Ok, was afraid of that. Trying to take an easy way out usually bites you sooner or later. Thanks, xml it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the Word Doc in base64 and then put it into the xml wrapper.

Apache commons offers a decent encoder/decoder: http://commons.apache.org/codec/

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you're sending data over a socket so you're free to use whatever protocol (even if you event one!) you want. I think I'd do something like this:

Send the following over the socket:

```
command     : 1 byte (command, enum, let '1' signifiy add_task)
header_size : 4 byte (1 int, size of header. Header is a XML snippet of meta data like doc_name)
doc_size    : 4 byte (1 int, size of raw document )
header_data : header_size bytes of data, interpret as an xml string
doc_data    : doc_size bytes, interpret as your raw data type
```

Of course there are many higher level protocols that can probably handle this and much more. At least this way you're avoiding weird escape sequences, base64, regex, and other parts that will get you into trouble.